# Angular Firestore: Check if data exist and update a global variable based on that

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function, google-cloud-firestore

**Requested behaviour:** 
I would like to create an AngularService which checks if a certain document exists and updates a global variable based on the result.

**Current State** 
The function checks the existence of the document successfully. It also updates the global variable in the if/else statement.

**issue** 
Even, the first part works well, it always returns "undefined".

How can I fix that? Is it related to function scope?

My Service:

```js
export class ProfileFollowService {

  //global variable which should be updated
  followState: boolean;
  
  constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  checksFollow(followingID: string, followerID: string): boolean {
    const followDoc =
    this.angularFirestore.collection(`users/${followingID}/following`).doc(followerID).ref;

    followDoc.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
          this.followState = true;
      } else {
          this.followState = false;
      }
    });
    return this.followState;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

followDoc.get() is async function that returns promise. In order to return updated this.followState you have to wait for `then`

one way to do this is to use async / await

```
async checksFollow(followingID: string, followerID: string): boolean {
    const followDoc =
    this.angularFirestore.collection(`users/${followingID}/following`).doc(followerID).ref;

    return followDoc.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
          this.followState = true;
      } else {
          this.followState = false;
      }

      return this.followState;
    }); 
  }
```

In other part of your code where you call `checksFollow` you can put keyword `await` and wait for the response.

```
async someMethodToCallChecksFollow() {
    const result = await this.checksFollow();
    console.log(result);
}
```

If you want to use the response in your html, I would suggest changing followState from  primitive `boolean` to `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` and then call `this.followState.next(true)`

For example:

```
export class YourService {
  public followState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  async checksFollow(followingID: string, followerID: string): boolean {
    const followDoc =
    this.angularFirestore.collection(`users/${followingID}/following`).doc(followerID).ref;

    return followDoc.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
          this.followState.next(true);
      } else {
          this.followState.next(false);
      }

      return this.followState.getValue();
    }); 
  }
}
```

And then in your html you can use `async` pipe.

```
<div *ngIf="yourServiceInstance.followState | async">It is true</div>
```

Comment: That is a good start. But my idea behind the service is to display a button in an angular component based on true or false. If I add a return statement to someMethodToCallChecksFollow() and call it in my angular component it returns [object Promise]. Do I have to convert the data? If so, do you know how or what else I can do?

Comment: You can use async pipe it will wait for your method to resolve

Comment: But if I want to call that method from a component, I get this errror: `Type 'Promise<Boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.` I merged your suggestions and asked a new questions based on that: [edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020175/angular-firestore-display-a-button-depending-of-a-returned-boolean-which-checks) It would be awesome if you can have a look at that :)